# Read XML into DataSet faster way than with XmlReader in .net framework 2.0, window CE 6.5

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, windows-ce

I am using a webservice to generate some XML and transfer to `DataSet`.
Below code to read XML into `DataSet`:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlData);
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream);
    ds.ReadXml(reader);
}
```

XMl file as below, get from SOAP:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <ID>1002065</ID>
    <Item_No>0000043</Item_No>
    <Description>Test2</Description>
    <Remarks />
    <Ref_No />
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ID>1002034</ID>
    <Item_No>0000054</Item_No>
    <Description>Test2</Description>
    <Remarks />
    <Ref_No />
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I found out that the `ds.ReadXml` is taking 42 secs to load 1700 records is very slow. 
Using framework 2.0 
Any suggestions to increase the speed?

Now change to

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
XmlNode nodes = doc.DocumentElement;

string ID = "", Item_No= "", Description = "", Remarks = "", Ref_No= ""; 

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Item_No");
dt.Columns.Add("Description");
dt.Columns.Add("Remarks");
dt.Columns.Add("Ref_No");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    ID = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
    Item_No = node.SelectSingleNode("Item_No").InnerText;
    Description = node.SelectSingleNode("Description").InnerText;
    Remarks = node.SelectSingleNode("Remarks").InnerText;
    Ref_No = node.SelectSingleNode("Ref_No").InnerText;

     dt.Rows.Add(ID, Item_No, Description, Remarks , Ref_No)
}
     dataSet ds= new dataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

But the download speed is still same for 1700 records in 40 secs.

Comment: how about `XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream);`

Comment: what is the reference for XDocument?

Comment: As an aside, you can use a `StringReader` instead of getting all the string bytes and creating a memory stream over them. `XmlReader.Create` has an overload that accepts a `TextReader`.

Comment: How large is your xml?  Huge file you must use xmlReader.  You code is probably slow because you are reading the entire file in one lump.  I usully use XmlReader along with XElement to read one section of the code at a time which is usually very quick.  Need to see sample of xml to give better answer.  See my response at following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Comment: @jdweng had add in my xml file in question. My xml file will have 20 columns for each table and there will be around 2000 records each time to read.

Comment: @user14351: I assume you are using the .NET Compact Framework? I suggest you specify whether you are using version 2.0 or 3.5 because this affects some of the answers you will get.

Comment: sorry, my fault. didn't mention is for framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code example, I think you are make things more complicated than you need. I suggest that you do skip the buffering part. Instead write

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList element;
doc.load(file.xml);
//do stuff...
```

or

```
XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlNode));
while (xReader.Read()) 
{ 
switch (xReader.NodeType) 
 { 
  case XmlNodeType.Element: 
   //Do stuff...
   break;
  case XmlNodeType.Text: 
   //Do some stuff...
   break; 
  case XmlNodeType.EndElement: 
   //Do some other stuff...
   break; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: We use `XmlNode nodes = doc.DocumentElement;` and then `foreach (XmlNode node in nodes.ChildNodes)` (top example) and it works well. Using .NET v2.0 Compact Framework on Windows CE 5.0 and 6.0.

Comment: @AlainD I had changed my code to read xmlnode into dataset, but i still facing the same problem. Any other ways to speed up the reading? thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question with the version of .NET CF and Windows CE (5.0, 6.0, 7.0) you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try code below.  It can be made dynamic if each table has different columns.  Not sure if your xml posted truly represents actually xml.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Table")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Table");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement table = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    Table newTable = new Table() {
                        id = (int)table.Element("ID"),
                        no = (string)table.Element("Item_No"),
                        description = (string)table.Element("Description"),
                        remarks = (string)table.Element("Remarks"),
                        refNo = (string)table.Element("Ref_No")
                    };
                    Table.table.Add(newTable);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public class Table
    {
        public static List<Table> table = new List<Table>();

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string no { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public string refNo { get; set; }
    }
}
    //<ID>1002065</ID>
    //<Item_No>0000043</Item_No>
    //<Description>Test2</Description>
    //<Remarks />
    //<Ref_No />
```

Comment: Need Library System.Xml.Linq

Comment: @jdweng: `Linq` is added from .NET Compact Framework v3.5 only (and is not available in v2.0). The OP needs to specify the version of .NET being targeted.